# The keyboard changes its state after a space

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, mask

I had a problem when I type the text I do not want the keyboard changes automatically, but after a space keyboard changes to the original state. 
For example, I want to dial numbers that I move into this state the keyboard:[image] 
 **But when I need to enter the number followed by a space, the keyboard itself is changed automatically:**[image]
And it is necessary that the user himself can change the state of the keyboard, if it is necessary to enter characters. I use a mask on the text of Edit Text. With the help of this library set mask: [MaskFormatter](https://github.com/AzimoLabs/MaskFormatter). an example of a mask:
 `private static final String MASK = "99 AA 999999";
    private EditText mInputCertificate;
    @Override
    public void setViews(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Some code
        mInputCertificate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.input_car_certificate);
        MaskFormatter maskFormatter = new MaskFormatter(MASK, mInputCertificate);
        mInputCertificate.addTextChangedListener(maskFormatter);
        }`
***There are ways to solve this problem?***

Comment: You added inputType for EditText?

Comment: in xml file did not set this option and the library I downloaded and built into an application like java classes, it removed the replacement keyboard in the class CharInputType.

Answer (score 0):

I made my custom TextWatcher for EditText:

```
private String getString (String s) {
    String newValue = s.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    /*if (newValue.length() < 2 || newValue.length() >= 4) {
        mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    } else {
        mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }*/
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i =0; i < newValue.length(); i++) {
        if (i == 2 || i == 4) {
            builder.append(' ');
            builder.append(newValue.charAt(i));
        } else {
            builder.append(newValue.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    Log.d("EDITTEXT", "getEditable " + s);
    String text = getString(s.toString());
    mEditText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
    mEditText.getText().clear();
    mEditText.append(text.toUpperCase());
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    mEditText.setSelection(mEditText.length());
}
```

This work for me. And I used .append(SomeText) instead .setText(SomeText).